# Why doesn’t my background thread run?

Tags: objective-c

The doBackgroundWork method does not get called from the startDoingWork method.

```
 threading.h
    ------------
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface threading : NSObject {

        NSConditionLock* theConditionLock;
        NSMutableArray* workItems; 

    }
    -(void)startDoingWork;
    -(void)doBackgroundWork;
    -(void)notifyBackgroundThreadAboutNewWork;
    @end


    threading.m
    -------------

    #import "threading.h"

    enum{
        workToDoNow = 1,
        workNotToDoNow = 0
    };

    @implementation threading

    -(id)init{
        if (self = [super init]) {
            theConditionLock = [[NSConditionLock alloc]initWithCondition:workNotToDoNow];
            workItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
        return self;
    }
    -(void)startDoingWork{
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doBackgroundWork) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    }
    -(void)doBackgroundWork{
        while (YES) {
            NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
            NSArray* items = nil;
            NSLog(@"Going to lock!!");
            [theConditionLock lockWhenCondition:workToDoNow];
            items = [NSArray arrayWithArray:workItems];
            [workItems removeAllObjects];
            [theConditionLock unlockWithCondition:workNotToDoNow];
            NSLog(@"Finished the work!!");
            [pool drain];
        }
    }
    -(void)notifyBackgroundThreadAboutNewWork{
        NSLog(@"Into the Background new work!!");
        [theConditionLock lock];
        [workItems addObject:@"Hello"];
        [theConditionLock unlockWithCondition:workToDoNow];
        NSLog(@"Finished and came out!!");
    }
    @end

    main.m
    ------
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "threading.h"

    int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        threading* threads = [[threading alloc]init];
        [threads notifyBackgroundThreadAboutNewWork];
        [threads startDoingWork];
        [pool drain];
        return 0;
    }
```

the detachNewThread:selector:toTarget:withObject method does not get called when debugged.

Comment: 1) Does the execution reach the `[threads startDoingWork]` line? 2) What do you get in the console? 3) Did you consider using [GCD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch) instead?

Comment: @zoul:yes it reaches that. when its on detachNewThreadSelector its not jumping onto the doBackgroundWork thread.Its coming out of the startDoingWork method.

Comment: I'm gettting the output of notifybackgroundThreadAboutNewWork method alone in the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it that your main ends that fast that the background thread has no chance to start? You know, before even the runtime manages to set up and start new thread, the app is finished and all the threads are killed/closed/whatever. You can put the main thread to sleep for a second to see if the background threads starts running.

Comment: Hi Alvin, good to know. See you in "Getting a runtime exception" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your worker thread selector should take exactly one argument I believe.